# Cleaning expired session from database

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am currently storing my sessions inside my *mysql database* however i see a lot of sessions whose date of expiry has reached .Now i don't have any other kind of script running for collecting up expired sessions however i read about garbage collection but there is a less chance that garbage collection will take care of large amount of expired sessions as soon as they expire.

> I am looking forward for a script or alternative solution which automatically deletes expired sessions?

Comment: it'd take all of about 5 lines of code to write such a script.... connect, then `delete from session where last_usage <= (now() - interval $life_of_session)`.

Comment: do you expect a script from crontab as an answer, or some php solution?

Comment: look into `cron jobs`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to implement your session handler class, and it's gc function can delete old session data:

```
function gc($lifetime) {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb", "myuser", "mypassword");

    $sql = "DELETE FROM session WHERE session_lastaccesstime < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " . $lifetime . " SECOND)";
    $db->query($sql);
}
```

> Garbage collection is performed on a random basis by PHP. The
>   probability that garbage collection is invoked is decided through the
>   php.ini directives session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor. If
>   the probability is set to 1 and the divisor is set to 100 for example,
>   the garbage collector has a 1% chance of being run on each request
>   (1/100).

You need to set gc to be the handler:

```
session_set_save_handler(array($sessionHandler,"open"),
                        array($sessionHandler,"close"),
                        array($sessionHandler,"read"),
                        array($sessionHandler,"write"),
                        array($sessionHandler,"destroy"),
                        array($sessionHandler,"gc"));
```

See more about how to use it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: $result = $this->link->query("DELETE FROM Session WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Session_Expires) + ".$lifetime.") < ".$lifetime.")");

Comment: i am using this query , do you think i have written the right query?

Comment: No. Try this: "DELETE FROM Session WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Session_Expires) + ".$lifetime.") < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))"

Comment: i found this query in php documentation page by some user :3.Dayum.

Comment: Whatever you wish. Just don't be surprised that it won't do what you want :)